# Text overflowing beyond the div

Tags: css, html

#### Text overflowing beyond the DIV while scrolling

How can prevent the text from exceeding the DIV box while scrolling?
What are the changes that I need to change?

```css
 .trending {
   width: 50%;
   float: left;
   padding-top: 6px;
 }
 .trending-box {
   margin-left: 5px;
   background-color: #e9ebee;
   color: #4b4f56;
 }
 .trending-box h3 {
   text-align: center;
   padding: 3px 3px 3px 3px;
 }
 .trending-align {
   background-color: palegreen;
   padding: 3px 3px 3px 3px;
 }
 .trending-content {
   background-color: #111;
   width: 100%;
 }
```

```html
<div class="trending">
  <div class="trending-box">
    <h3>Top Trending</h3>
    <div class="trending-align">
      <div class="trending-content">
        Some random text
      </div>
    </div>


  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I don't see any overflowing text in your example.

Comment: while scrolling to maximum the text inside the DIV box while exceeds..

Comment: While scrolling what? Nothing is scrollable. You need to create an example that shows the issue you describe.

Comment: Try to zoom the page to maximum to see the text exceeding problem or run the code from your system sir..

Comment: Zooming is not the same as scrolling.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I don't get what you mean by scroll 
But possibly you mean to  extra wrap the text inside the div 
, here the solution for that 
just include
 word-wrap: break-word;

```css
.trending {
   width: 50%;
   float: left;
   padding-top: 6px;
 }
 .trending-box {
   margin-left: 5px;
   background-color: #e9ebee;
   color: #4b4f56;
 }
 .trending-box h3 {
   text-align: center;
   padding: 3px 3px 3px 3px;
 }
 .trending-align {
   background-color: palegreen;
   padding: 3px 3px 3px 3px;
 }
 .trending-content {
 word-wrap: break-word;                     //here 
   background-color: #111;
   width: 100%;
 }
```

```html
<div class="trending">
  <div class="trending-box">
    <h3>Top Trending</h3>
    <div class="trending-align">
      <div class="trending-content">
        Some random textdddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd
      </div>
    </div>


  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What does this have to do with scrolling?

Comment: fix for text goes beyond div.. and right its not any mean for scroll

Comment: So, not really an answer to the question then.

Comment: .I was confused zooming with scrolling. Issue fixed. Thank you for the help @Turnip

Answer (score 0):

```css
    
    
    .trending {
   width: 50%;
   float: left;
   padding-top: 6px;
 }
 .trending-box {
   margin-left: 5px;
   background-color: #e9ebee;
   color: #4b4f56;
 }
 .trending-box h3 {
   text-align: center;
   padding: 3px 3px 3px 3px;
 }
 .trending-align {
   background-color: palegreen;
   padding: 3px 3px 3px 3px;
 }
 .trending-content {

 background-color:  #111;
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    overflow: scroll;
 }
```

```html
<div class="trending">
  <div class="trending-box">
    <h3>Top Trending</h3>
    <div class="trending-align" >
      <div class="trending-content" >
        Some random text       Some random text       Some random text       Some random text       Some random text       Some random text       Some random text       Some random text
      </div>
    </div>
    
   
</div>
```

you  can use  **CSS overflow Property**

```
overflow: scroll;
```

try this  - http://jsfiddle.net/MadhawaMB/rJy94/41/

```
.trending-content {

    background-color:  #111;
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    overflow: scroll;
    }
```